# Don't cache errors with publishReplay

Tags: javascript, caching, rxjs

I have some Javascript code:

```
public browse = (): Observable<IAttribute[]> => {
    if (!this.attributes) {
       this.attributes = Observable
            .defer(() => this.http.browse())
            // cache 1min
            .publishReplay(1, 60000)
            .refCount()
            .take(1);
    }
    return this.attributes;
}
```

A problem I have come across is that errors seem to get cached. The specific situation was that a user's session timed out and so the endpoint returned a 401 so the user got redirected to the login page - but because it was within 1 minute of the previous request attempting to go to the attributes page would re-throw a 401 instead of making the request fresh.

Is there a way to set this up so it retries on errors, but only when requesting a cached version? i.e. I don't want the original request which returned the 401 to retry, but the second request should have retried the request.

Comment: Note that`publishReplay(1), refCount()` 'replays' the last good value AND error. This is due to it using ReplaySubject internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to still get the error in the original subscriber right?

This is not so beautiful, someone can probably do this better. And this is probably the worst demo of RxFiddle (there some bugs regarding subjects), but I'm sharing it nonetheless...

Here we go, [view this on RxFiddle:](http://rxfiddle.net/#type=editor&code=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)

```js
let tries = 0
let httpMock = new Rx.Observable(o => {
  if (tries == 0) {
    setTimeout(() => o.error(new Error()), 10)
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => o.next("value"), 10)
  }
  tries++
})

let replaySubject = null
function browse() {
  return Rx.Observable
    .defer(() => httpMock)
    .do(false, (e) => replaySubject = null)
    .multicast(() =>
      replaySubject || (replaySubject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1)), 
      cache => cache.take(1)
    )
    .let(obs => replaySubject ? replaySubject : obs)
}

browse().subscribe(console.log, console.warn)

setTimeout(() => {
  browse().subscribe(console.log, console.warn)
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `catch(Observable.empty())` before your publish replay

Comment: so that does not send the error downstream... OP probably wants to show it somewhere in the user interface